# How can I enter real numbers in an array with at most 3 digits precision in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Actually, I have written a basic code, which includes input command for that:
f23=float(input("Enter The 23 Element of Array:"))

but it does not have any limitation with digits, and I'd like to restrict it up to 3 digits. for example : 2.253

does anybody know what to do?

Comment: what do you mean by 'restricting', should the program auto-correct the digit inserted?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to *auto-correct* the user then you should use the builtin `round` function or the `format` function.

or, if you want to raise an exception when it does that, i would suggest to equate the rounded and the original version.

a **basic** implementation would be something like this.

```
arr = []
no_digits = 3
for x in range(26):
    arr[x] = round(float(input(f"the {x}th element is: ")),no_digits)
```

or with list comprehension:

```
arr = [round(float(input(f"the {x}th element is: ")),no_digits) for x in range(26)]
```